# WordPress - Custom Post type, Custom role, Custom Capability

Tags: php, wordpress, woocommerce

I am stuck in a problem assigning custom capability with custom post type to a custom role.

The issue is i want to remove the **Add New** ( **Not with a CSS hack or by unsetting menu item** ) option of my custom post type. I have already come across answers that suggest many solutions but none of them works perfectly.

**Closest to what i want is this :**

```
register_post_type( 'custom_post_type_name', array(
  'capability_type' => 'post',
  'capabilities' => array(
    'create_posts' => 'do_not_allow', // false < WP 4.5, credit @Ewout
  ),
  'map_meta_cap' => true, // Set to `false`, if users are not allowed to edit/delete existing posts
));
```

This code removes the Add New link but it assigns the default **post** slug for capabilities.Notice line 2 of above code. If i change it to my custom post type slug, it stops working and i can't even go posts page.

**One thing to keep in mind is that i am working with custom role, which has only read capability by default.**

If i also assign the **edit_posts** capability then my objective is achieved, but then user can also access posts and comments, which i do not want.

**Woocommerce is doing this.** I dive into woocommerce code and add this line where it registers its products and orders.

```
'capabilities'        => array( 'create_posts' => 'do_not_allow' ),
```

And everything works as i want. I have explored woocommerce code all day but can't find how it is doing this. Can someone else help me out on this with another pair of eyes ? :)

Much appreciated. Thanks..

Comment: Have you tried setting 'create_posts' to null or empty string?

Comment: yes i did with same results

Comment: I believe you are setting this at the wrong place. You should give this capability a unique name, and then add it to the array of capabilities for respective roles, OR, while defining the custom role set the corresponding capability to false. Refer to https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8198038/wordpress-capabilities-for-custom-post-types?rq=1

Comment: Can you please update your question with little more info, like, what really you want accomplish ? 

Currently what I'm guessing from here is, you tried to hide CPT add new capability to specific user role ? but you also give that user role to edit and modify, re-edit capability/permission ?

Comment: @Gaurav do not allow is the right thing to do instead of setting false as you are suggesting. And i have already tried all of these things.

Comment: @mlbd you are right. That is what i want to do.

Answer (score 3):

I already mention to you that give us little more details about the plan that you want to do?

Here is the solution that I think it would be helpful for you.

If you want to used `map_meta_cap => true` then you will need to change `capability_type` as well with your own type, see more https://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/register_post_type#capability_type

But if you set your own `capability_type` value then you will need to add capability to users role those you want to add.

here is a complete example.

```
if ( !class_exists( 'WPSE64458_CPT_Register' ) ) {
  class WPSE64458_CPT_Register {

    function __construct() {
      add_action( 'init', array( $this, 'wpse64458_register_post_types' ), 5 );
      add_action( 'admin_init', array( $this, 'wpse64458_add_caps' ), 5 );
      add_filter( 'register_post_type_args', array( $this, 'wpse64458_modify_cpt_registry' ) , 10, 2 );

    }

    /**
     * Register core post types.
     */
    public function wpse64458_register_post_types() {

      if ( ! is_blog_installed() || post_type_exists( 'member' ) ) {
        return;
      }

      register_post_type( 'member',
        apply_filters( 'wpse64458_callb_post_type_member',
          array(
            'labels'              => array(
              'name'                  => __( 'Members', 'domaintext' ),
              'singular_name'         => __( 'Member', 'domaintext' ),
              'all_items'             => __( 'All Members', 'domaintext' ),
              'menu_name'             => _x( 'Members', 'Admin menu name', 'domaintext' ),
              'add_new'               => __( 'Add New', 'domaintext' ),
              'add_new_item'          => __( 'Add new member', 'domaintext' ),
              'edit'                  => __( 'Edit', 'domaintext' ),
              'edit_item'             => __( 'Edit member', 'domaintext' ),
              'new_item'              => __( 'New member', 'domaintext' ),
              'view'                  => __( 'View member', 'domaintext' ),
              'view_item'             => __( 'View member', 'domaintext' ),
              'search_items'          => __( 'Search members', 'domaintext' ),
              'not_found'             => __( 'No members found', 'domaintext' ),
              'not_found_in_trash'    => __( 'No members found in trash', 'domaintext' ),
              'parent'                => __( 'Parent member', 'domaintext' ),
              'featured_image'        => __( 'Member image', 'domaintext' ),
              'set_featured_image'    => __( 'Set member image', 'domaintext' ),
              'remove_featured_image' => __( 'Remove member image', 'domaintext' ),
              'use_featured_image'    => __( 'Use as member image', 'domaintext' ),
              'insert_into_item'      => __( 'Insert into member', 'domaintext' ),
              'uploaded_to_this_item' => __( 'Uploaded to this member', 'domaintext' ),
              'filter_items_list'     => __( 'Filter members', 'domaintext' ),
              'items_list_navigation' => __( 'Members navigation', 'domaintext' ),
              'items_list'            => __( 'Members list', 'domaintext' ),
            ),
            'public'              => true,
            'show_ui'             => true,
            'capability_type'     => 'member',
            'map_meta_cap'        => true,
            'menu_icon'          => 'dashicons-groups',
            'publicly_queryable'  => true,
            'exclude_from_search' => false,
            'hierarchical'        => false, // Hierarchical causes memory issues - WP loads all records!
            'rewrite'            => array( 'slug' => 'member' ),
            'query_var'           => true,
            'supports'            => array( 'title', 'editor', 'thumbnail', 'excerpt' ),
            'has_archive'         => 'members',
            'show_in_nav_menus'   => true,
            'show_in_rest'        => true,
          )
        )
      );

    } // end of wpse64458_register_post_types


    /**
     * Get capabilities.
     *
     * @return array
     */
     private function wpse64458_set_caps() {
      $capabilities = array();

      $capability_types = array( 'member' );

      foreach ( $capability_types as $capability_type ) {

        $capabilities[ $capability_type ] = array(
          // Post type
          "edit_{$capability_type}",
          "read_{$capability_type}",
          "delete_{$capability_type}",
          "edit_{$capability_type}s",
          "edit_others_{$capability_type}s",
          "publish_{$capability_type}s",
          "read_private_{$capability_type}s",
          "delete_{$capability_type}s",
          "delete_private_{$capability_type}s",
          "delete_published_{$capability_type}s",
          "delete_others_{$capability_type}s",
          "edit_private_{$capability_type}s",
          "edit_published_{$capability_type}s",

          // Terms
          // "manage_{$capability_type}_terms",
          // "edit_{$capability_type}_terms",
          // "delete_{$capability_type}_terms",
          // "assign_{$capability_type}_terms",

        );
      }

      return $capabilities;
    }

    /*
      Add Capability
     */
    public function wpse64458_add_caps(){

      global $wp_roles;

      if ( ! class_exists( 'WP_Roles' ) ) {
        return;
      }

      if ( ! isset( $wp_roles ) ) {
        $wp_roles = new WP_Roles();
      }

      $capabilities = $this->wpse64458_set_caps();

      foreach ( $capabilities as $cap_group ) {
        foreach ( $cap_group as $cap ) {
          $wp_roles->add_cap( 'editor', $cap );
          $wp_roles->add_cap( 'administrator', $cap );
        }
      }
    }

    public function wpse64458_modify_cpt_registry( $args, $post_type ){

      // Do not filter any other post type
      if ( 'member' !== $post_type ) {

        // Give other post_types their original arguments
        return $args;

      }

      if( current_user_can('editor') ) {
        $args['capabilities']['create_posts'] = false;
      }

      // Give the custom-css-js post type it's arguments
      return $args;

    }


  }
}
```

then inherite the `class` with `new WPSE64458_CPT_Register();`

With this example I disable editor role to add new member post functionality. modify whatever you like, or you can do this others as well. but you previously mention that you already tried to follow WooCommerce, actually they also do this way,

Hope it make sense to you.

HappyCodding!

Comment: Thanks you for such a great and detailed answer. But i have already done this. And as i mentioned in the question. I need this for a custom role.Which will only have read capability. It works with any default role or the custom role if it has edit_posts capability along with read. But i do not want to give edit_posts capability to the custom role. That is it. Everything else is exactly like you coded and explained. Hope this clears what you were asking for.

Comment: Glad to hear that you already did this one. 

Anyway, If you really don't want to give other capabilities other then read capability only then I really confused what is left for to do this control?

If I don't give user role to edit_posts or edit_cpt then I can't find any issue here?

However, HappyCodding! :)

Comment: That is the problem. I just can't figure that what is missing here. I thought may be someone else will be able to find out. It does not work unless i give edit_posts permission. And if i give that then everything works absolutely fine. I want to give and i have given edit_cpt but i don't want to give edit_posts

Comment: I am awarding this bounty to you since you have made an honest attempt and your answer is valid. But since it does not solve my problem i cannot accept it. Cheers.

Answer (score 3):

You can restrict specific user role to custom post by below script :

**Add custom Role**

```
add_action('init','add_my_custom_role');
    function add_my_custom_role() {

     add_role('my_custom_role',
                'Custom Role',
                array(
                    'read' => true,
                    'edit_posts' => false,
                    'delete_posts' => false,
                    'publish_posts' => false,
                    'upload_files' => false,
                    'publish_posts' => false,
                    'create_posts' => false, 
                )
            );
       }
```

**Register Custom post**

```
add_action( 'init', 'my_custom_post_type');
function my_custom_post_type() {
     $args = array(
 'label'               => __( 'Custom post', 'custom-text-domain' ),
 'description'         => __( 'Custom post', 'custom-text-domain' ),
 'labels'              => $labels,
 'supports'            => array( 'title', 'comments', 'revisions', ),
 'hierarchical'        => false,
 'public'              => true,
 'show_ui'             => true,
 'rewrite'             => $rewrite,
                        'capability_type'     => array('custom_post','custom_post'),
                        'map_meta_cap'        => true, // Set to `false`, if users are not allowed to edit/delete existing posts 
 );
 register_post_type( 'custom_post', $args );
}
```

**Allow user capabilities for post on the basis of roles**

```
    add_action('admin_init','custom_post_add_role_caps',999);
        function custom_post_add_role_caps() {

     // Add the roles you'd like to administer the custom post types
     $roles = array('my_custom_role','editor');

     // Loop through each role and assign capabilities
     foreach($roles as $the_role) { 

          $role = get_role($the_role);

                  $role->add_cap( 'read' );
                  $role->add_cap( 'read_custom_post');
                  $role->add_cap( 'read_private_custom_post' );
                  $role->add_cap( 'edit_custom_post' );
                  $role->add_cap( 'edit_custom_post' );
                  $role->add_cap( 'edit_others_custom_post' );
                  $role->add_cap( 'edit_published_custom_post' );
                  $role->add_cap( 'publish_custom_post' );
                  $role->add_cap( 'delete_others_custom_post' );
                  $role->add_cap( 'delete_private_custom_post' );
                  $role->add_cap( 'delete_published_custom_post' );

     }
}
```

I hope this will help you, to get more help please visit

https://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/register_post_type

and

https://codex.wordpress.org/Roles_and_Capabilities